# Can't reference array's item by name indexOf()

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

So I have this dataBase that is gonna be used in the app.get function below. The goal is to make the app.get send the first item in the array dataBase (which is the array "posts") as the value for the object's atribute "posts:". In case I don't set any names for the array and call it in the app.get as "posts: dataBase[0]", it works - the forEach() can read it; otherwise, it seems it's not called as an array since the .forEach() can't be used.

```
const dataBase =
[
    posts = [
        {
            title: "Post 1",
            text: "Lorem ipsum",
            stars: 2
        },
        {
            title: "Post 2",
            text: "Lorem ipsum"
        },
        {
            title: "Post 3",
            text: "Lorem ipsum",
            stars: 5
        }
    ],
    ads = {}
]

app.get("/posts", (req, res)=>{
    res.render("posts", 
    {
        title: "Basic Project: Posts",
        posts: dataBase[dataBase.indexOf("posts")]
    }
    )
})
```

IN THE .ejs FILE:

```
<article class="content">
    <h1>POSTS:</h1>
    <% posts.forEach(item=>{ %> <!-- ERROR: forEach is not a function -->
        <div>
            <% if (item.stars){ %>
                <% for(let i = 0; i < item.stars; i++){ %>
                    <img src="images/star.pgn"> 
                <% } %> 
            <% } %>
            <h3><%= item.title %></h3>
            <p><%= item.text %></p>
            <br>
        </div>                
    <% }) %>
</article>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing the concepts of arrays and objects. In JS they are not the same thing.

Your database should probably be:

```
const dataBase = {
    posts: [
        {
            title: "Post 1",
            text: "Lorem ipsum",
            stars: 2
        },
        {
            title: "Post 2",
            text: "Lorem ipsum"
        },
        {
            title: "Post 3",
            text: "Lorem ipsum",
            stars: 5
        }
    ],
    ads: {}
}
```

Then you can access posts simply with `dataBase.posts`.

Here is some more details about arrays vs objects: https://medium.com/@zac_heisey/objects-vs-arrays-42601ff79421.

Comment: Oh I see. But can't I have an array inside and array?